# ubuntu - install subversion from source - missing APR

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, svn

Because I need a bug fix which is not available in Ubuntu's repository version of subversion, I am installing it from source.

On running `./configure`,  I get an error:

```
configure: WARNING: APR not found
The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.
Please install APR on this system and supply the appropriate
--with-apr option to 'configure'

or

get it with SVN and put it in a subdirectory of this source:

   svn co \
    http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/branches/1.2.x \
    apr

Run that right here in the top level of the Subversion tree.
Afterwards, run apr/buildconf in that subdirectory and
then run configure again here.

Whichever of the above you do, you probably need to do
something similar for apr-util, either providing both
--with-apr and --with-apr-util to 'configure', or
getting both from SVN with:

   svn co \
    http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr-util/branches/1.2.x \
    apr-util

configure: error: no suitable apr found
```

### Notes:

1) I have already installed libapr1

2) I am not able to install svn client, to follow the instructions in the error message (apt-get install svn - no package found - I have main, universe, restricted, multiverse in sources.list)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To compile a program depending on a library you generally need the developer package.
In your situation you need to do: `apt-get install libapr1-dev`. And don't forget to repeat it with `apt-get install libaprutil1-dev`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Getting another error now. By any chance do you know the package for this?  (Searched on google but didnt find apt-get package) ............................... configure: WARNING: APRUTIL not found
The Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APRUTIL) library cannot be found.
Either install APRUTIL on this system and supply the appropriate

Comment: same thing install the package called: libaprutil1-dev